# Unit relative to width or height of an element

Tags: html, css

I always have this doubt.

When we use, for example, `width: 50%` , this 50% is relative to width of its parent.

For example i has this code

```
<div id="root">
    <div id="child">

    </div>

    <div id="child2">

    </div>
</div>
```

and this css

```
#root{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#child{
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    background: yellow;
}

#child2{
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3EKzj/

If `#root` has a width of 200px, `#child` has a width of 100px...

but is it possible that width of `#child` is 50% of the width of `#child2` (25px), using any css property or function?

I know that in `transform: translate(50%,25%)` 50% is relative to own width elemen and 25% to own height element, so is it possible that with any funcion i can get width or height of others elements?

Thanks!

Comment: See my update for a JavaScript solution.

Comment: In 10 years of web development I've never even thought of the possibility of needing this  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not without JavaScript. CSS has no way of applying properties of one element to another other than via inheritance.

**Update**
With JavaScript, the solution looks like this:

```
var child = document.getElementById('child');
var child2 = document.getElementById('child2');

child.style.width = (child2.clientWidth  / 2) + 'px';
```